# MySQL relation between 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables: users, logs, log_entries. One user has many logs, one log has many entries. It would look like this

[image: zzz]

Lets say there are 100 users, each user has 1000 logs and each log has 1000 entries. It means there would be 100 000 000 lines in log_entries table and when I want to check log from date x it needs to filter the data I want from 100 000 000 lines.

What is the correct solution for this please?

Comment: I think I'd have an auto inc primary in logs, session_id, so a unique row in logs for each user/session, then use that as foreign key in entries, a simpler join

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INNER JOIN` and `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users U
  INNER JOIN Logs L ON U.UserId = L.UserId
  INNER JOIN Log_Entries LE ON 
     CONCAT(L.UserId,'|',L.Session_Start) = LE.UserIdSession_Start
```

I would however recommend changing your table structures -- this is very odd.  At minimum, add a Log_Id to your Logs table and have that field in your Log_Entries table as well.

Comment: So is it ok if there will be a huge amount of lines in the log_entries table? Shouldn't I make it totally different? Thanks.

Comment: @LukAss741 -- I'd add an Auto_Increment field to your Logs table (LogId).  Then you can use that field in your Log_Entries Table to join on and remove your first field altogether.  The JOIN above gets very strange, especially if the dates aren't stored exactly in the same format (you may have to start replacing characters for example to even get the above join to work).